# Error al iniciar el cliente MongoDB con NodeJS

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Buenas tardes comunidad , he intentado utilizar el MongoStore pero me esta arrojando este error :

```
Assertion failed: You must provide either mongoUrl|clientPromise|client in options
```

/home/oliver/Escritorio/NodeJS-ExpressJS-MongoDB/node_modules/connect-mongo/build/main/lib/MongoStore.js:119
throw new Error('Cannot init client. Please provide correct options');
^

Error: Cannot init client. Please provide correct options
at new MongoStore (/home/oliver/Escritorio/NodeJS-ExpressJS-MongoDB/node_modules/connect-mongo/build/main/lib/MongoStore.js:119:19)
at Function.create (/home/oliver/Escritorio/NodeJS-ExpressJS-MongoDB/node_modules/connect-mongo/build/main/lib/MongoStore.js:136:16)
at file:///home/oliver/Escritorio/NodeJS-ExpressJS-MongoDB/server.js:12:23
at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:152:23)
at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:166:24)
at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

y este es mi codigo:

```
import express from 'express';
import session from 'express-session';
import MongoStore from 'connect-mongo';

const MONGO_URL = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/auth'
const app = express();

app.use(session({
    secret:'ESTO ES SECRETO',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: MongoStore.create({
        mongourl:MONGO_URL,
        autoReconnect: true
    })
}))
app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    req.session.cuenta = req.session.cuenta ? req.session.cuenta + 1 : 1;
    res.send(`Hola! Has visto esta pagina : ${req.session.cuenta}`);
})
app.listen(3000,() =>{
    console.log('listening on port 3000');
})
```

NOTA:  ya intente declarando import connectMongo from 'connect-mongo', const MongoStore = connectMongo(session); y tampoco funciono.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que tienes mal formateada la propiedad, el nombre correcto de la llave es `mongoUrl` con u mayúscula en camelcase, y tu lo tienes como `mongourl` fíjate bien en [las opciones](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo#options) que recibe el modulo, espero que te sea de ayuda, un saludo.

Comment: excelente, ya las horas en el pc me tenían ciego si era eso. Saludos y muchas gracias.